# How do I change text every time I click the button?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm clicking a button to make a call to an API to get a random fact and length. This is then displayed in two input fields which works. I'm struggling with how to change the text in the input fields to the new fact and length from the API when the button is clicked again. I know it is something simple but can't seem to find the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
 <template>
    <form>
        <header>
            <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="./assets/logo.svg" width="300" height="300" />
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="idFact" v-model="facts">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="idLength" v-model="lengths">
            <br>
            <br>
            <button v-on:click="callAPI" type="button">Call</button>
        </header>
    </form>
</template>

    <script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts: '',
            facts: '{fact}',
            lengths: '{length}',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async getData() {
            try {
                let response = await fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact");
                this.posts = await response.json();;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        },
        callAPI() {
            this.facts = this.posts.fact
            this.lengths = this.posts.length
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getData();
    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke the `getData` method inside the click handler `callAPI`, and remove the call from `created` hook in order to avoid redundant calls:

```html
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts: '',
            facts: '{fact}',
            lengths: '{length}',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async getData() {
            try {
                let response = await fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact");
                this.posts = await response.json();;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        },
        callAPI() {
            this.getData()
            this.facts = this.posts.fact
            this.lengths = this.posts.length
        }
    },
    
}
</script>
```